# Validate Sum up array field from foreach Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have working `foreach array` where it collects all `tasks` and it contains `weight` for each task.

Here's my working code

```
foreach ($arr4 as $row4) {
    $taskCode = strtoupper(str_random(12));
    $insert_data5[] = array(
        'projCode'  =>  $projCode,
        'taskCode'  => $taskCode,
        'taskWeight'  =>  $row4['weight'],
        'plan_days' =>  $row4['planned_days'],
        'actual_days'  =>  $row4['actual_days'],
        'deleted'  =>  0,
        'by_id'  => auth()->user()->id,
        'updated_by'    =>  auth()->user()->name,
        'created_at'    =>  now(),
        'updated_at'    => now(),
        );

}

dd($insert_data5);
```

OUTPUT

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to validate if the sum up of `taskWeight` of `5 Tasks` doesn't reached 100% this will show an error message.

As of now my idea is to use `validator` but I have no idea how can I calculate the array fields of `taskWeight`

```
  $validator = Validator::make(
                $insert_data5,
                [
                   ......
                ]
            );


   if($validator->fails()){
                return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()])
                ->with('modal',$modal);
            }
```

Comment: What do you want here? did you mean to ask how to limit total sum of `taskWeight` to be less than 100? and what does that `5 Tasks` mean? did you mean to say you want sum of `5 tasks` or there are total `5 tasks`?

Comment: I mean, if I sum up all the `tasks` using `taskWeight` this should not exceeds 100%. I just want to limit the total sum up into 100% and if the total sum up of `taskWeight` is `<100` there's a validation will appear that says it should be exact 100%

Comment: why do you want to do it on the server side?

Comment: because the `$insert_data5` contains the data of excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my problem

I declare `$ttlTaskWeight = 0;` outside of foreach

Then as suggested do the sum up inside of the `foreach`

like this

`$ttlTaskWeight += $row4['weight'];`

and I did this to validate if it exceeds 100% or not

```
    if($ttlTaskWeight != 100){
                return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with(['errors'=> [0=> 'Total Task Weight must be exact 100%']])
                ->with('modal',$modal);
            }
```

and the output is this

[image]

Comment: `99 !=100 ` true and `101 !=100` also true